# Combining two match patterns in one

Tags: scala

How does one combine (in a nice way) two Scala match'es?

First I have to test if an Option is a valid value:

```
myOption match {
  case Some(op) =>
    doSomethingWith(op)
  case None =>
    handleTheError()
```

Then if op was valid, I want to test for another pattern:

```
Path(request.path) match {
  case "work" => {
    println("--Let's work--")

  }
  case "holiday" => {
    println("--Let's relax--")
  }
  case _ => {
    println("--Let's drink--")
  }
}
```

I could combine them like this:

```
myOption match {
  case Some(op) =>
    doSomethingWith(op)
    Path(request.path) match {
      case "work" => {
        println("--Let's work--")          
      }
      case "holiday" => {
        println("--Let's relax--")
      }
      case _ => {
        println("--Let's drink--")
      }
    }
  case None =>
    handleTheError()
```

But, it feels sloppy. Is there a better way to combine them in some way or another.

**Update**

Apologies, I should have explained better. I'm actually trying to find out if there is a known pattern for simplifying (or factoring out) these control structures. For example (imagine this was true):

```
x match {
 case a => {
   y match {
    case c => {}
    case d => {}
   }
 }
 case b => {}
}
```

equals

```
x -> y match {
  case a -> c => {}
  case a -> d => {}
  case b => {}
}
```

I was just wandering if someone has already identified some refactoring patterns for control flow, much like algebra where `2(x + y) = 2x + 2y`

Comment: What do you typically do in doSomethingWith(op)?

Comment: I'ts hard to tell in such a generic case, why don't you internalize the second pattern matching in `doSomethingWith` (or in a function that combines the 2 of them)?

Comment: Thanks, please see the update in my question for why and what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
myOption map { success } getOrElse handleTheError
```

or with `scalaz`,

```
myOption.cata(success, handleTheError)
```

where `success` is something like

```
def success(op: Whatever) = {
  doSomethingWith(op)
  Path(request.path) match {
    case "work"    => println("--Let's work--")
    case "holiday" => println("--Let's relax--")
    case _         => println("--Let's drink--")      
  }
}
```

#### Update

Your pseudocode

```
x -> y match {
  case a -> c => {}
  case a -> d => {}
  case b => {}
}
```

can be literally translated to scala as

```
(x, y) match {
  case (a, c) => {}
  case (a, d) => {}
  case (b, _) => {}
}
```

It looks nice (and that's probably what you wanted) if inner matcher have only few options (`c` and `d` in this case), but it leads to code duplication (repeating of pattern `a`). So, in general I'd prefer `map {} getOrElse {}`, or separation of pattern-matchers on smaller functions. But I repeat, in your case it looks reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. That is a solid suggestion. Please see the update in the question. I'm not as much trying to solve 'this' problem as I'm looking for ways to generally improve the quality of code. Apologies for not giving a better explanation earlier.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I don't think this is a repeat of anything, since (a, c) and (a, d) are in fact two distinct patterns. The fact that one element in the pattern is the same, does not deteriorate the quality of the code in any way. Just an opinion ;-)

Comment: Yes, in your case it's reasonable. I just wanted to say, it will repeats when amount of `case`s is large.

Answer (score 3):

If the scrutinees (the expressions on which you match) do not depend on each other, i.e. you can compute them independently, you could perform both `match`es at the same time by wrapping the scrutinees in a tuple.

So your example:

```
x match {
 case a => {
   y match {
    case c => fooC(...)
    case d => fooD(...)
   }
 }
 case b => fooB(...)
}
```

could be rewritten as:

```
(x,y) match {
  case (a, c) => fooC(...)
  case (a, d) => fooD(...)
  case (b, _) => fooB(...)
}
```

...as long as `y` doesn't depend on `x`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the type I was hoping for - I think ;-) One question though: '...as long as y doesn't depend on x' in this context could be rewritten '... as long as x does not have to be calculated before y'? Or am I missing what you mean by y depending on x?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by dependence.